# Need help figuring out what capacitor to use and how to get a second light to turn off

Tags: led, capacitor, ac

I’m new to electrical engineering but I’m working on a circuit that has a AC power supply of 105-125 VAC at 50/60 HZ. I have already figured out how to get the first light to blink on, but idk what I need to set my capacitor to (liking back on it  not sure if I need one) or how I need to add a second light that will blink whenever the circuit drops bellow 50 VAC. If anyone can help I really need it.

My project I’m working on is for school, where I have a wire and when the voltage is adjust it needs to indicate if the voltage is lower than 50vac by a “yellow” led should be blinking but if it is above a green led should be blinking

Link to my very very basic diagram-
https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjAzCAMB00IQVhrATATiQFiWMSaA7NBmmNESElCjtQKYC0+AUAEojYAcIGAbF148Y4ainzRRUuElYB3cNmx9BYZUpXQF4QQKGqYOkfvUr92xWcNgyh7WCIrrLjWmi8w4BKhTsGAM4AlgEALgCGAHYAxgw61u6ebmha8fxSjoKJ4ESCDkhS2WDpIGhIaiWFonLR4HZgaJ71DdLwiF5wCBSI7RAQPLlOqF3xdqbNaEZW9Y11k9aWc5qlHsuLZRWFRPOVrABOpdu6UhDux6LdiwnlIBCEpTfaAObLG6-cvDLxyc5uj6zFSanDIlO47KoAEwYADNwgBXAA2oSYCIYELEMmGYB0YPOuLe2gA9nwQPwtFxSBhhtAUth1NB+GVqQgMLlykyqlSIKwgA

Comment: Thanks for adding those details. Several points are still not clear enough for me to understand (e.g. where the "AC power supply of 105-125 VAC at 50/60 HZ" fits into the design - it isn't shown on the schematic - and how that is related to the variable voltage that your circuit are supposed to react to). I will delete my earlier comment asking for more details, as it is now obsolete, given that you have added some details. Perhaps someone else will understand your updated question better than I do. If you have any more details, I recommend you also add those. Good luck with your project!

Comment: So my instructor is using an electric cattle fence and those were the specification he gave use, but I couldn’t figure out how I needed to wire up a schematic to do this, that why I turned to here to see if anyone had any idea of how to help me, the design was more or less what I thought might work, but it has been changed from a DC circuit because I originally thought it was a dc output but I was wrong. Idk if this helps any

Comment: What do you expect the capacitor to do? Seems your question is about a voltage level detection not an AC timing issue (that the capacitor would affect).  Also consider first converting the input signal to DC, (with a diode and capacitor), add a voltage reference, add a voltage divider using resistors, and change the logic gate to a op-amp like component to create a "Voltage Level Detector" or "Voltage Comparator" circuit, (look those up).

Comment: @andru can you post a schematic as a picture?